# How do I do the equivalent of Solidity's bytes32(a_signed_integer) in JavaScript?

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript, encoding

I've got an app that takes various kinds of input via an HTML form, but always ends up sending it to a contract as `bytes32`. The expectation is that another contract that ultimately consumes the data will cast it into the type that it's expecting, which may be `bytes32`, `uint256` or `int256`.

For unsigned integers I'm taking a `BigNumber` object, calling `toString(16)` on it to get hex, then left-padding it to 64 digits, and appending `0x`. But for signed integers, which may be negative, I presumably need to handle the two's complement system; What's the appropriate way to do this?

Comment: BN.js (a dependency of web3 v1.0) has two methods `toTwos` and `fromTwos` that can be used to get the two's complement to an arbitrary length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using BN.js as suggested by @Ismael:

```
function numStringToBytes32(num) { 
   var bn = new BN(num).toTwos(256);
   return padToBytes32(bn.toString(16));
}

function bytes32ToNumString(bytes32str) {
    bytes32str = bytes32str.replace(/^0x/, '');
    var bn = new BN(bytes32str, 16).fromTwos(256);
    return bn.toString();
}

function padToBytes32(n) {
    while (n.length < 64) {
        n = "0" + n;
    }
    return "0x" + n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
var utf8 = require('utf8');

function padToBytes32(n) {
    while (n.length < 64) {
        n = n + "0";
    }
    return "0x" + n;
}

function fromUtf8(str) {
    str = utf8.encode(str);
    var hex = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var code = str.charCodeAt(i);
        if (code === 0) {
            break;
        }
        var n = code.toString(16);
        hex += n.length < 2 ? '0' + n : n;
    }

    return padToBytes32(hex);
};

// not tested yet...
function toUtf8(hex) {
    // Find termination
    var str = "";
    var i = 0, l = hex.length;
    if (hex.substring(0, 2) === '0x') {
        i = 2;
    }
    for (; i < l; i += 2) {
        var code = parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16);
        if (code === 0) {
            break;
        }
        str += String.fromCharCode(code);
    }

    return utf8.decode(str);
};

module.exports = {
    fromUtf8,
    toUtf8
};
```

```

Answer (score 0):

Using only [BN.js](https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/)

```js
let num = -1234;
let bytes32 = "0x"+(new BN(String(num))).toTwos(256).toString('hex',64);
```

Using [web3.js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.7/web3-eth-abi.html#encodeparameter)

```js
let num = -1234;
let bytes32 = web3.eth.abi.encodeParameter('int256', String(num));
```

This is working in smart-contract like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
contract TestConversion {
    int256 val;
    function set(bytes32 _val) public {
        val = int256(_val);
    }
    function get() public view returns(int256){
        return val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange!  Can you please edit your answer and add a bit more?  Did you try with a negative number as the question asks?